# DB2 + ODBC Connection Error

Tags: sql, db2, odbc

I'm trying to connect to an external database (System DNS) from my server (Windows Server 2012 with DB2) and I'm getting the following error:

"The database alias or database name "" was not found at the remote node"

Could somebody help me with this connection?

Thank you

Comment: Show us the connection string/statement.

Comment: Also include additional details about your client environment.  What DB2 client is installed on your server, etc.